# Can't understand what UIScenes are

Tags: ios, swift

I can't find a clear definition of what UIScenes are

Are they just for handling the background calls? Are they like a ViewController? Do we use them often or nah?

Comment: See WWDC 2019 [Architecting Your App for Multiple Windows](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/258/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest thing is that scenes set up multiple window support. It is also useful for SwiftUI.

The SceneDelegate controls what is displayed on the screen "to manage life-cycle events in one instance of your app's user interface.", while the AppDelegate controls your entire app life-cycle.

Read the [App and Environment Article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment) and [scenes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes) from Apple instead of UIScene documentation.

Scene:

> Scene, Manage multiple instances of your app’s UI simultaneously, and
>   direct resources to the appropriate instance of your UI.

We had only one scene back then before iOS 13, So the only thing we need to run ViewControllers simultaneously was multiple Windows on top of each other. But now, each application can have multiple instances running at the same time! Each scene has its own state and it might be in the foreground while others are in the background or are suspended, while Window was completely dependent on the application itself.

Imagine we have 2 view controllers (consider there are no scenes) running on the left and right side of the device and then we need to show a banner. Using the old window method will show the banner on both of them! And if you need to pick one, you may end up finding the correct controller and presenting the banner on it.

So apple introduced Scene, a container for each separate instance of the app. So you can manage each one separately and each of them acts as a separate app. It has its own windows and controllers. But all of them are managed by a single object, UIApplication.shared and it has a delegate to handle general events (usually from outside of the app) and entire application life cycle.

Comment: This answer is copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/61848068/1452589

While putting links as answers are not advisable, copying the answer without crediting the original poster is just plagiarism.

Comment: @AnnaFortuna Thanks for your mentions. Actually, when i realized this, I wanted to remove the answer, but it was accepted I was unable to remove it.